# Why is auto_ptr specialized for void?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, void, template-specialization

I have decided to move over from raw pointers to smart pointers, so I though I could start by reading http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr.

There I've seen that they are specialized for `void`.

Why is this? Is it useful in any situation?

Comment: Because `void` isn't a complete type?

Comment: `auto_ptr` is officially deprecated. It's probably the *last* smart pointer type you should consider/investigate.

Comment: Use `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was done in [LWG 541](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#541).  The issue has the complete rationale.  But in short it was done for compatibility with what was then `std::tr1::shared_ptr` (later standardized to `std::shared_ptr`).

If you are investigating moving from raw pointers to smart pointers I strongly recommend you use `unique_ptr` in favor of `auto_ptr`.  `auto_ptr` is deprecated, and for good reason.  `unique_ptr` is the recommended replacement for `auto_ptr`.

[Here is a link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1856.html#20.4.5%20-%20Class%20template%20auto_ptr) explaining the rationale for deprecating `auto_ptr`, and replacing it with `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::auto_ptr` was deprecated since C++11. Consider to study other smart pointers like [`std::shared_ptr`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [`unique_ptr`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead.

The answer to your question is (As far I know): `std::auto_ptr` uses `delete` to release the memory of its internal raw-pointer, but deleting `void*` has no sense at all, because void is an incomplete type and can never be the type of an object. Yo have to cast void* to the corresponding type of the pointed data before deleting it. So this smart pointer provides an specialization for `void` which has less capabilities (Note that [the reference says](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr) that the void specialization has no member functions).

Comment: @KerrekSB thats true. I will modify the phrase to "deleting `void*` has no sense at all, because void is an incomplete type and can never be the type of an object. Yo have to cast void* to the corresponding type of the pointed data before deleting it."